# Is it possible to limit folder size in NexentaStor Community Edition

Tags: nfs, zfs, nexenta

For example if i have a 4TB ZFS Volume, is it possible to create 3 folders and then limit each folder to, say, 2GB. If so, how?

I have googled hard and wide but to no avail - all i get is info on the 18TB license restriction.

All and any advice gladly taken.

---EDIT

After testing all the below answers worked, I'm giving my correct answer to GUI related answer as i feel its the most correct solution to the problem, however the rest are useful to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the web GUI, navigate to `Data Management` -> `Shares` and select the necessary folder.

Under `Read-Write Parameters`, you can enter a quota to limit to how much space the folder can consume (Referenced Quota), or how much the folder and its snapshots, etc. can take (Quota). The normal suffixes (G,M,K) apply.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the _Nexenta way_.  Looks like this is just setting the zfs config properties - so this should be the same end result as setting on the command line, I believe.

Comment: Also +1 for making me remember how to scroll the page...

Answer (score 1):

What you were looking for is the "quota" feature of zfs.

To set a 2GB quota on `dir/whereever` in a pool named `pool`:

```
zfs set quota=2G pool/dir/whereever
```

And, to check a quota:

```
zfs get quota pool/dir/whereever
```

Comment: I had thought about that but wasn't sure if it was the correct solution to the problem and just assumed it would cause chaos as nexenta would throw errors when the limit was hit

Answer (score 1):

In the NMS admin panel, you can set this via going to Data Management -> Data Sets -> Folders -> Show ->  -> Quota

[image]

This is essentially the same thing as "zfs set quota".  Note the quota applies to that entire ZFS filesystem (or Folders), not just within specified folders.  If you need different quotas, you'll have to use different filesystems.